# What's the name of this set

Tags: polynomials

Let's take field $(K, +,\times,0,1)$. Let's take set $S(K) \subset K$ such that:

\[ \forall~e \in K,\exists~a \in S(K),\exists~p \in K: e = a \times p \times p \]
\[ \lnot \exists~a, b \in S(K), \exists~p \in K, (a \times p \times p = b \land a \neq b) \]

For example $S(\mathbb{R}) = \\{-1, 1\\}$, $S(\mathbb{C}) = \\{1\\}$, $S(\mathbb{Z}_3) = \\{1, 2\\}$, $S(\mathbb{Z}_5) = \\{1, 2\\}$. Of course sets are not unique like $S(\mathbb{R}) = \\{-e,\pi\\}$ is also possible.

(Sorry if I misuse terms - I haven't found english translation - but I found it useful to generalize the signature of quadratic polynomials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am deciphering your notation correctly, I would call $S$ "a set of coset representatives for $K^{\times}/(K^{\times})^2$."

Comment: I haven't check it fully but from what I understend it looks like this.